# Magento 2.3.4: What is the use of cronjob consumers_runner cronjob?

Tags: magento2.3

I am looking to change the frequency of certain cronjobs to improve the performance and want to know what is the use of cronjob consumers_runner cronjob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cronjob will (as its name already implies) run the consumers registered in Magento so that they can process the messages stored in the queues from both the Magento database and RabbitMQ.